# Cookie set to subdomain when :all option is used

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cookies

In my session controller, I want to set a cookie when user logs-in.

Say I visit *http://buy.example.com/login*, and the controller will handle the login as well as the cookie setting like the following:

```
    cookies[:status] = { value: 'y', :domain => :all }
    redirect_to referrer_url
```

I see that the cookie is set under the domain *.buy.example.com*, instead of *.example.com*.

The setting `:domain => :all` is not having any effect at all.

I am using Rails 3.2.11. The test is done in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set up your config/initializers/session_store.rb file

```
YourAppName::Application.config.session_store :cookie_store, 
:key => '_yourAppName_session', domain: {
  production: '.example.com',
  development: '.lvh.me'
}.fetch(Rails.env.to_sym, :all)
```

With this configuration you can use `lvh.me:3000` as the url in development.

Comment: I have, but I think this is irrelevant since this is not a session cookie.